# Port forwarding testing

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port, ip-camera

In trying to check if I setup Port Forwarding correctly for my IP security camera none of the services report the port open. I can access the camera from within the LAN, but can't see it from the WAN. When a port check service tests the port; is it looking that the router has an open port designated?, or that there is a device properly working behind the designated port? I am trying to figure out if I messed up port forwarding at the router, or the camera port forwarding is not working. Thanks

Comment: Are you actually testing your WAN connection from a machine outside your LAN, or just using the WAN IP from inside the LAN?

Answer (score 0):

Your router needs to correctly forward the port and secondly the service on your PC or relevant device behind the router should also accept the incoming request. Any instance of firewall blocking the port shall as well be reported as 'Closed' by the port checking services over the internet.

Router is acting as an intermediate device to forward the incoming request to designated port (by port forwarding), Open port testing can also be done by directly providing the WAN IP of your PC (Assuming router is not present)

Answer (score 0):

A small list of ideas.

1. You could also try testing with [NetBrute](http://www.rawlogic.com/netbrute/)
2. ISPs typically have a small set of blocked ports for residential addresses, commonly port 80. So, try use another port if possible, or route a different external port.
3. It may help to go one port outside of the 'bounds' of the port you are forwarding. For example, if you're trying to forward port 98, open the range of ports from 97 to 99. *This may be an old technique no longer in use.
4. Also, some all-in-one home routers have a 'mirror the same inside port' checkbox that makes sure the external and internal port are the same.

Answer (score -1):

I am testing if the port is open using canyouseeme and portforward.com and they do not report an open port. When my laptop is connected to the router I can see and manipulate the camera by simply typing the camera IP (192.168.1.108) I open the TCP port in the router with the number provided by the camera. Then I check using the router (external) IP (from my ISP) and the port using any port check service, and no luck.

Thanks Pat. It makes sense the both need to work (router + device) I am pretty sure that is the camera that is not accepting the requests, since I have tried at three different location, programming three different routers. Will look further into the Dahua forums.

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the author's question.